# Read Lotus Notes with Python

Tags: python, lotus-notes

I have some Lotus Notes table on a Note document.This one has an URL like this:

```
Notes://[...]
```

I would like to parse it in Python, but I can't manage it.
I found several sources, telling me to act like it:

```
import win32com.client
session = win32com.client.Dispatch('Lotus.NotesSession')
session.Initialize(r'pppppppp')
db = session.GetDatabase('',r'dddddddd.nsf')
view = db.GetView(r'vvvvvvvv')
doc = view.GetFirstDocument()
print doc.GetFirstItem('iiiiii').Values

domino return string as unicode
```

But I have an error already at the second line.
[image]

Do you know how I should do it?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You need Lotus (IBM/HCL) Notes installed on the Windows computer where the Python code is running. If it is already installed, you need it to be registered correctly. If your Python environment is 64 bits, be aware that until recent versions the Lotus Notes client code was only 32 bits. In some older versions, the installer may not have properly registered the classes and it was necessary to use the regsvr32 command to do this. There are (probably) some old threads here on StackOverflow that cover this.